# Can't go into safe mode: "User Profile Service service failed the logon"

Tags: windows-7, boot

My Win 7 pc boots fine in normal mode, but in safe mode, once it gets to the blue "Loading user account" screen, it errors out with a "User Profile Service service failed the logon" message box and after about 2 seconds reboots by itself. What might be the reason

Comment: Have you tried any diagnostics like disk checks (chkdsk), or a System File check (sfc)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your computer can't login to your network with your user profile, but more info is needed to diagnose.  The following forum discusses the error and provides a detailed solution:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-security/user-profile-service-service-failed-the-logon-user/4ed66b21-c23e-42f1-98b2-706dcf931fae

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot in normal mode then try to active the `Admin` account if you have not enabled it yet. Rub `cmd` as administrator by right click on it then type the exact command and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Admin account will be enabled.
`c:\>net user administrator /active:yes`

[image]

You can try to fix with Safe Mode - repeatedly tap F8 as you bootup. The ADMIN account in Safe
Mode has no password by default (so unless someone changed the password it should be available).

Some programs like the Google Updater (if you added the Google Toolbar, Chrome or Google Earth)
has been known to cause this issue.
Error message when you log on to a Windows Vista-based or Windows 7-based computer by using a
temporary profile: [The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947215).
How to Fix the Error [The User Profile Service failed the logon. User profile cannot be loaded.](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/130095-user-profile-service-failed-logon-user-profile-cannot-loaded.html)
[Fix a corrupted user profile](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-AU/help/769495bf-035c-4764-a538-c9b05c22001e1033.mspx)

You can find more information on [Microsoft windows 7 security forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/the-user-profile-service-service-failed-the-logon/9390be2a-9e45-4265-bccf-fce6574f6d9f).

Comment: For a shell command, text might actually be better than a screenshot (as it would allow copy&paste).

Comment: @OliverSalzburg thanks for mention it and don't feel hesitation to edit my answer if they not look helpful.